# React JS saving my code not working properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React JS and I have a problem with my code. I wrote this peace of code and some how every time I save my codes get distorted. Maybe my code organizer extension mess things up. but I'm not sure. Here is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
state = {
articles : [
  { id : 1 , title : 'article 1' , body : 'this is article 1'},
  { id : 2 , title : 'article 2' , body : 'this is article 2'},
  { id : 3 , title : 'article 3' , body : 'this is article 3'},
],
title : "soroush ghatran"
}

loadMore = () => {
  let articles = [
    { id : 4 , title : 'article 4' , body : 'this is article 4'},
    { id : 5 , title : 'article 5' , body : 'this is article 5'},
    { id : 6 , title : 'article 6' , body : 'this is article 6'},
  ]


  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      articles : [...prevState.articles , ...articles]
    }
   })
}

render() {
console.log(this.state)
let articleList = this.state.articles.map((article , index) => <Card key={index} title= 
 {article.title} body={article.body} />)
 
return (
  <div className="app">
    {
      articleList
    }

    <button onClick={this.loadMore}>load more</button>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

I've checked it many times. I don't no if there is something wrong with my code or not. Anybody can help me?

Comment: It's probably your code editor. Can you share code editor you use please ?

Comment: I am using VS code

Answer (score 0):

It has got nothing at all to do with your code. Please follow these steps:

1. Open your IDE.
2. Check if you have used any extensions that can format code in your IDE.
3. If there are any extensions related to code formatting, try to disable those.
4. If there are no extensions and you still face issues, please adjust your IDE settings. If you mention which IDE you are using, I can provide the steps to modify the settings accordingly.

P.S - Please try to mention sufficient details while asking a question, like the name of the IDE and the extensions you are using would be highly relevant here. Please follow these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @hoob_nerd Thanks for your response. I am using VS code.

Comment: Did you try the steps that I have mentioned?